# Half transparent screen without lights?

Tags: java, opengl, shader, lwjgl, slick2d

I am following this tutorial:
https://github.com/mattdesl/lwjgl-basics/wiki/ShaderLesson6
I want to make 2d lightning but whenever I render it I get a black screen.
This is my code:

**Main Class**

```
public class Main {

    private static final int WIDTH = 1280;
    private static final int HEIGHT = 720;
    private static int shaderProgram;

    private static int vertexShader;
    private static int fragmentShader;

    private static Terrain terrain;

    public static final float DEFAULT_LIGHT_Z = 0.075f;
    public static final Vector4f LIGHT_COLOR = new Vector4f(1f, 0.8f, 0.6f, 1f);
    public static final Vector3f LIGHT_POS = new Vector3f(0, 0f, DEFAULT_LIGHT_Z);

    public static final Vector4f AMBIENT_COLOR = new Vector4f(0.6f, 0.6f, 1f, 0.2f);

    public static final Vector3f FALLOFF = new Vector3f(.4f, 3f, 20f);

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        initDisplay();
        initGL();

        terrain = new Terrain();
        terrain.createTerrain();

        createShader();

        gameLoop();

        removeShader();

    }

    private static void gameLoop() {
        while (!Display.isCloseRequested()) {
            glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
            glUseProgram(shaderProgram);


            float x = Mouse.getX() / (float)Display.getWidth();
            float y = Mouse.getY() / (float)Display.getHeight();
            LIGHT_POS.x = x;
            LIGHT_POS.y = y;

            int location_lightPosition = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "LightPos");

            int location_resolution = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Resolution");
            int location_lightColor = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "LightColor");
            int location_ambientColor = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "AmbientColor");
            int location_falloff = glGetUniformLocation(shaderProgram, "Falloff");

            glUniform3f(location_lightPosition, LIGHT_POS.x, LIGHT_POS.y, LIGHT_POS.z);
            glUniform2f(location_resolution, WIDTH, HEIGHT);
            glUniform3f(location_lightColor, LIGHT_COLOR.x, LIGHT_COLOR.y, LIGHT_COLOR.z);
            glUniform4f(location_ambientColor, AMBIENT_COLOR.x, AMBIENT_COLOR.y, AMBIENT_COLOR.z, AMBIENT_COLOR.w);
            glUniform3f(location_falloff, FALLOFF.x, FALLOFF.y, FALLOFF.z);

            terrain.drawTerrain();
            glUseProgram(0);

            Display.update();
            Display.sync(60);

        }
    }

    private static void initGL() {
        glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION);

        glLoadIdentity();

        glOrtho(0, WIDTH, 0, HEIGHT, -1, 1);

        glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW);

        glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);

        glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 1);
    }

    private static void initDisplay() {
        try {
            Display.setDisplayMode(new DisplayMode(WIDTH, HEIGHT));
            Display.create();

        } catch (LWJGLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static void createShader() {
        shaderProgram = glCreateProgram();
        vertexShader = glCreateShader(GL_VERTEX_SHADER);
        fragmentShader = glCreateShader(GL_FRAGMENT_SHADER);
        StringBuilder vertexShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        StringBuilder fragmentShaderSource = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/me/mateo226/shaders/vertexShader.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                vertexShaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Vertex shader wasn't loaded properly!");
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }
        try {
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("src/me/mateo226/shaders/fragmentShader.txt"));
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                fragmentShaderSource.append(line).append("\n");
            }
            reader.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.err.println("Fragment shader wasn't loaded properly!");
            Display.destroy();
            System.exit(1);
        }

        glShaderSource(vertexShader, vertexShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(vertexShader);
        if (glGetShader(vertexShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(vertexShader, 500));
            System.err.println("Vertex shader not compiled!");
        }
        glShaderSource(fragmentShader, fragmentShaderSource);
        glCompileShader(fragmentShader);
        if (glGetShader(fragmentShader, GL_COMPILE_STATUS) == GL_FALSE) {
            System.out.println(GL20.glGetShaderInfoLog(fragmentShader, 500));
            System.err.println("Fragment shader not compiled!");
        }

        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, vertexShader);
        glAttachShader(shaderProgram, fragmentShader);
        glLinkProgram(shaderProgram);
        glValidateProgram(shaderProgram);
    }

    private static void removeShader() {

        glDeleteProgram(shaderProgram);
        glDeleteShader(vertexShader);
        glDeleteShader(fragmentShader);
        Display.destroy();
    }

}
```

This is my
How I load the textures, bind and draw them in the terrain class:

```
private Texture tex;
private Texture texNormal;

tex = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/wall.png")));
texNormal = TextureLoader.getTexture("PNG", new FileInputStream(new File("res/wallNormal.png")));
    GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE1);
            texNormal.bind();
            GL13.glActiveTexture(GL13.GL_TEXTURE0);
            tex.bind();
            glBegin(GL_QUADS);
            {
                glTexCoord2f(0, 0);
                glVertex2f(x, y);
                glTexCoord2f(0, 1);
                glVertex2f(x, y + height);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 1);
                glVertex2f(x + width, y + height);
                glTexCoord2f(1, 0);
                glVertex2f(x + width, y);
            }
            glEnd();
```

I don't think the problem is in the above code, but in the shaders:

**Vertex:**

```
    #version 400 core
varying vec2 vTexCoord;
void main() {
    gl_TexCoord[0] = gl_MultiTexCoord0;
    vTexCoord = gl_TexCoord[0].xy;
    gl_Position = ftransform();
}
```

**Fragment**

```
    #version 400 core
varying vec4 vColor;
varying vec2 vTexCoord;

//our texture samplers
uniform sampler2D u_texture;   //diffuse map
uniform sampler2D u_normals;   //normal map

//values used for shading algorithm...
uniform vec2 Resolution;      //resolution of screen
uniform vec3 LightPos;        //light position, normalized
uniform vec4 LightColor;      //light RGBA -- alpha is intensity
uniform vec4 AmbientColor;    //ambient RGBA -- alpha is intensity 
uniform vec3 Falloff;         //attenuation coefficients
void main(void) {
    //RGBA of our diffuse color
    vec4 DiffuseColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);

    //RGB of our normal map
    vec3 NormalMap = texture2D(u_normals, vTexCoord).rgb;

    //The delta position of light
    vec3 LightDir = vec3(LightPos.xy - (gl_FragCoord.xy / Resolution.xy), LightPos.z);

    //Correct for aspect ratio
    LightDir.x *= Resolution.x / Resolution.y;

    //Determine distance (used for attenuation) BEFORE we normalize our LightDir
    float D = length(LightDir);

    //normalize our vectors
    vec3 N = normalize(NormalMap * 2.0 - 1.0);
    vec3 L = normalize(LightDir);

    //Pre-multiply light color with intensity
    //Then perform "N dot L" to determine our diffuse term
    vec3 Diffuse = (LightColor.rgb * LightColor.a) * max(dot(N, L), 0.0);

    //pre-multiply ambient color with intensity
    vec3 Ambient = AmbientColor.rgb * AmbientColor.a;

    //calculate attenuation
    float Attenuation = 1.0 / ( Falloff.x + (Falloff.y*D) + (Falloff.z*D*D) );

    //the calculation which brings it all together
    vec3 Intensity = Ambient + Diffuse * Attenuation;
    vec3 FinalColor = DiffuseColor.rgb * Intensity;
    gl_FragColor = vColor * vec4(FinalColor, DiffuseColor.a);
    //gl_FragColor = texture2D(u_texture, vTexCoord);
}
```

I know there is a lot of code in here, and I can move it to pastebin if you want!
Please I am stuck, help!
Any help is appreciated!
**EDIT:** I just realised I had varying "vColor" in my fragment shader and not my vertex shader. In my vertex shader I added `vColor = gl_Color;` Now I have a half transparent picture with no lights! :) Still need help though!

Comment: Have you tried break this into pieces? Is ambient term working? Is Diffuse ok? Maybe something is wrong with sampling the texture. Or Falloff has incorrect values. What is definitely working? Also check your shader program after linking. It should tell you about `vColor`, maybe more.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Thanks for the comment! I am really not sure what you mean? The shaders compile without any errors, I'll keep trying to solve it, looking forward to a possible answer from you!: )

Comment: Is program correctly linking? You don't check it after 'glLinkProgram'.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa I use glValidateProgram.

Comment: @AdrianKrupa Alright I fixed this. The problem was actually pretty stupid. I never set the LightColor's Alpha. > NEVER COPY PASTE <
Now I have a different problem though. My light isn't rendering as a circle of light, it's only showing half of the circle! I am going to start a new question for this :)